# Is there any relation between the Gershgorin circles of a matrix and its resolvent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

Let $A$ be a real symmetric matrix. Now fix a diagonal index say "i" and let $x > max-eigenvalue(A)$. Now is there any thing known about the Gershgorin circle of $[1/(x-A)]_{ii}$ in terms of the $A$? Any relation between the two?

Comment: where do you use the index $i$?

Comment: I corrected the question!